# Python TA-lib install error, how solve it?

Tags: python, linux, gcc, ta-lib

i install TA-lib with below command,

```
pip install TA-lib
```

but got this error "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1":

[image]

checked the [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib), installed the gcc, python-devel, libffi-devel, openssl-devel, but still not working!

then use  `conda install -c quantopian ta-lib=0.4.9` install talib but show 
 error "The following specifications were found to be in conflict:- py-xgboost, - ta-lib 0.4.9*"
then `conda info ta-lib, it return the"NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels"`

Comment: Please post errors as **text** (not images).

Comment: TLDR; "To use TA-Lib for python, you need to have the TA-Lib already installed." https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#dependencies

Answer (score 18):

I ran into exactly the same problem and was able to resolve it and install TA-lib on Linux and my OSX laptop. I'll stick to linux instructions here specifically CentOS, but the trick for both was the same... you must have TA-lib binary libraries installed on the machine before the python wrapper will install with pip.

The reference I used: ttps://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib

If this command is failing:

```
pip install TA-lib
```

Complaining about ta_libc headers as such:

```
func.c:256:28: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_libc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

You'll need to install TA-lib binaries before installing the python wrapper. I downloaded it as follows:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
```

Then uncompressed it, compiled it and installed:

```
tar -xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz 
cd ta-lib
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

If you don't have gcc and/or python3-dev on your machine, the above steps will give you hard time. Initially they were blowing up on me, so I satisfied the dependencies with:

```
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install python36-dev
```

Then re-run the steps from the beginning, this time with success. The above solution worked in my case.

I hope that helps, Good Luck!

BTW. My first ever answer here, I hope it helps someone, I've used StackOverflow to get passed many problems in the past, so I am hoping to reciprocate.

2018-08-30 UDPATE: I kept running into compiling issues specifically the error listed below would happen repeatedly. It turned out that I didn't have enough RAM (1GB) in the Virtual Machine. Solution ref:(https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/133) so I upgraded RAM (2GB) and issue went away.

```
talib/_ta_lib.c:208671:15: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

2021-03-06 UDPATE: OSX Catalina update! When compiling the TA-lib on OSX Catalina (10.15+) the above instructions did not work, I had to modify this:

```
tar -xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz 
cd ta-lib 
./configure 
make
sudo make install
```

After that, the pip install worked fine. –

Comment: should be `sudo yum install python36-devel`

Comment: Thanks ManualSchneid3r for cleaning up my instructions! Cheers!

Comment: OSX Catalina update!   When compiling the TA-lib on OSX Catalina (10.15+)  the above instructions did not work, I had to modify this: 

```
tar -xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz 
cd ta-lib
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After that, the pip install worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem with conda environment.using

```
conda install -c quantopian ta-lib
```

Answer (score 3):

So after some exploring, I found that there are 2 main problems that usually come up while trying to install TA-lib.

1. You did not pre-install the **TA-lib binaries** before running the pip install command
2. You have multiple versions of python, and that's breaking the installation

***Problem 1:*** 
First install the binaries:

1. Download ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
2. tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
3. cd ta-lib/
4. ./configure --prefix=/usr
5. make
6. sudo make install

and the run `pip install TA-lib`

***Problem 2*** 
This problem can arrive when you have different Python versions installed and you use a pip that's not the system's one. In that case, the non-system pip won't find the right version of Python headers. Causing the following error:
**command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1**

In this case, the solution is to find the right python header:

```
find / -iname 'Python.h'
```

Output:

```
/usr/include/python3.7m/Python.h
/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h
/home/ubuntu/workspace/blender-git/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/include/python3.7m/Python.h
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.8.5-h7579374_1/include/python3.8/Python.h
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.0-h6e4f718_3/include/python3.7m/Python.h
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/include/python3.8/Python.h
/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/sim/include/python3.7m/Python.h
/home/ubuntu/src/blender-deps/Python-3.7.7/Include/Python.h
/opt/lib/python-3.7.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h
```

Then export the correct one:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/home/ubuntu/src/blender-deps/Python-3.7.7/Include
```

Followed by the pip install command.

**OR**

Just switch the pip to another version of python (for example):

```
pip3.6 install TA-lib
```

Answer (score 1):

If below answer did not work for you(in my case it did not) you can find compiled whl file and install from there.

Here's [a link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) for compiled whl files for ta-lib.

Comment: Btw, these files are for Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed this issue in Linux:
First I downloaded C dependency from:
https://ta-lib.org/hdr_dw.html
Installed it at a local directory using:

```
./configure --prefix=<local_path_to_install_c_library>
make
make install
```

Then used `pip` to install `ta-lib`. Make sure to give `--global-options` to point `pip` to local library location.

```
pip install --upgrade --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L<local_path_to_install_c_library>/lib" --global-option="-I<local_path_to_install_c_library>/include" --install-option="--prefix=<local_path_to_install_python_lib>" ta-lib
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in a script called `install_talib.sh` or something, and then run `./install_talib.sh` from the command line.

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
if [ ! -f "ta-lib/CHANGELOG.TXT" ]; then
  tar zxvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
  cd ta-lib && sed -i.bak "s|0.00000001|0.000000000000000001 |g" src/ta_func/ta_utility.h && ./configure && make && sudo make install && cd ..
else
  echo "TA-lib already installed, skipping download and build."
  cd ta-lib && sudo make install && cd ..
fi
```

---

You may need to add permissions to the `install_talib.sh` file. You can do this using

`chmod u+x install_talib.sh`