# Unable to install Ta-lib on ubuntu - error with pip and make

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, lib

I've tried some alternatives but I can't install ta-lib or use make on my ubuntu ,when I send

```
pip install ta-Lib

Collecting ta-Lib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/05/d4c6a778d7a7de0be366bc4a850b4ffaeac2abad927f95fa8ba6f355a082/TA-Lib-0.4.17.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ta-Lib) (1.15.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: ta-Lib
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ta-Lib ... error
  Complete output from command /home/user/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ugk06wz4/ta-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-v2gctt6z --python-tag cp36:
  /tmp/pip-install-ugk06wz4/ta-Lib/setup.py:79: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
    warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  running build_ext
  building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
  gcc -pthread -B /home/user/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/home/user/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib/_ta_lib.o
  talib/_ta_lib.c:526:10: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
   #include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for ta-Lib
  Running setup.py clean for ta-Lib
Failed to build ta-Lib
Installing collected packages: ta-Lib
  Running setup.py install for ta-Lib ... error
    Complete output from command /home/user/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ugk06wz4/ta-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-kipfzx36/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /tmp/pip-install-ugk06wz4/ta-Lib/setup.py:79: UserWarning: Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.
      warnings.warn('Cannot find ta-lib library, installation may fail.')
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/deprecated.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_stream.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_abstract.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_pandas.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    copying talib/test_func.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    running build_ext
    building 'talib._ta_lib' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib
    gcc -pthread -B /home/user/miniconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/home/user/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/talib/_ta_lib.o
    talib/_ta_lib.c:526:10: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
     #include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
```

and this in red at the end
    Command

> /home/user/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-ugk06wz4/ta-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-kipfzx36/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ugk06wz4/ta-Lib/

when I type
`make`
or
`sudo make install`
I get this:
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.

what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance and thank you for your kindness

Comment: If a question is marked as a duplicate, please copy a link in the comments to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

sudo pip install -U setuptools

Or if it doesn't work to quote his comment:

```
Try this 'sudo -H pip install TA-Lib'
```

Comment: when i try the sudo pip install -U setuptools i get: "pip command not found" but i have pip and a updated version

Comment: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5pUn4a/TA-Lib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YtSAsJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5pUn4a/TA-Lib/

Comment: [Here's another solution that works on linux and mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66301514/6331353)