# Is it enough to install TA-Lib on Brew to use it? Pip throws me an error

Tags: python, homebrew, ta-lib

so I want to use the legendary TA-Lib on Python.

`brew install TA-Lib` worked.

But when I try to `pipenv install TA-Lib` or even `pip install TA-Lib` I get the following err:
`command 'clang' failed with exit status 1`

Can I use TA-Lib in my code from brew somehow? As it seems I cannot install it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

-- EDIT --
Try that way :

First download there :

[hyperlink to lib](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz)

Then,

```
tar xf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

'prefix' is really important. Don't miss it.

Last but not least:

```
pip install TA-Lib
```

Comment: Damned. Perhaps you have to upgrade some package before. What is written behind Status 1: ?

Comment: Now after installing numpy I get ```1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1```

Comment: probably due to an update. I'm afraid you'll have to pip install it from a wheel. It will be then ok

Comment: I don't remember exactly where I found it. It was tricky to find. But a question was hoping in my head. I've written pip3 install Ta-Lib, but did you try pip install too? I'll try to find out the whl meanwhule

Comment: No, I did not try pip install, my terminal does not even know the pip command. I found the following post to be helpful and am trying the solutions explained there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270089/installing-ta-lib-creates-gcc-error

Comment: Tried installing modified setup.py from git clone, managed to get as far as TA-Lib would show as installed on ```pip list``` but then if I tried to ```import talib``` in a script it would still give me Module Not Found error

Comment: did you install it in your env? or in 'base'?

Comment: I installed it in base.

Comment: Did you find it out?

Comment: Wasn't able to launch TA-Lib as much as I tried. The closest I got was managing to install it, yet when trying to import it would get module not found error. So compiling a list of technical analysis functions myself.

Comment: Ok, I got even further thanks to you. I managed to install ta-lib module using pipenv which was a no-go until now. However, when I import talib I get a new error: ```ImportError: 2): Symbol not found: _TA_ACOS
  Referenced from: /Users/teo/.local/share/virtualenvs/trendingcoin-nriNAUCq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/teo/.local/share/virtualenvs/trendingcoin-nriNAUCq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-38-darwin.so```

Comment: Seems like this guy is having the same problem (https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/311055895)