# Is it possible that Mac M1 users are not able to use Python wrapper for TA-Lib?

Tags: python, import, ta-lib

so I've been trying different methods to install TA-Lib, and found several different methods to install it, none of which have been easy, but even when TA-Lib is installed and appears on pip list, and even managed to install it on pipenv virtual environment, however if I actually want to go ahead and use it by typing

`import talib`

I get the following error:

`ImportError: 2): Symbol not found: _TA_ACOS   Referenced from: /Users/teo/.local/share/virtualenvs/trendingcoin-nriNAUCq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-38-darwin.so   Expected in: flat namespace  in /Users/teo/.local/share/virtualenvs/trendingcoin-nriNAUCq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-38-darwin.so`

Now I would like you to know that I have tried many different methods to install it, they are detailed in this thread: [Is it enough to install TA-Lib on Brew to use it? Pip throws me an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66014978/is-it-enough-to-install-ta-lib-on-brew-to-use-it-pip-throws-me-an-error)

As a wanna-be technical analyst, it would be sad if I can't use the infamous TA-Lib.

Comment: Python 3.9 is the first version of Python that supports Mac M1.

Comment: oh wow, good to know

Comment: Similar [github issue](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/409) (there may be others)

Comment: Here is a solution to install talib on an Mac M1 CPU: https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/408#issuecomment-855438491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make it work following some of the steps in this github issue: https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/381

```
$ arch -x86_64 brew install python@3.9
$ arch -x86_64 brew install ta-lib
$ arch -x86_64 brew link ta-lib
$ arch -x86_64 python3.9 -m pip install --no-cache-dir ta-lib
```

You'll need x86/brew and rosetta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64997047/3090309

NOTE: In my case, I went though so many intents, that really made the difference to include the `--no-cache-dir` option.

Answer (score 3):

The solution here seems to work:

https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/issues/408#issuecomment-839583759

`$ conda install -c conda-forge ta-lib`

Answer (score 2):

Install ta-lib

```
brew install ta-lib
```

Find pip command for your environment

```
which -a pip 
/home/<user>/.conda/envs/newenv/bin/pip <---------------
/usr/bin/pip
```

Install ta-lib wrapper via pip command

```
/home/<user>/.conda/envs/newenv/bin/pip install ta-lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did with my Mac M1:

```
# install python3.10
arch -arm64 brew install ta-lib
export TA_INCLUDE_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/include"
export TA_LIBRARY_PATH="$(brew --prefix ta-lib)/lib"
arch -arm64 python -m pip install --no-cache-dir ta-lib
```